# Difference between 继续 and 接着

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I learned 接着 a while ago, and the [CEDICT definition](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?wdqb=%E6%8E%A5%E7%9D%80) is as follows:

> to catch and hold on / to continue / to go on to do sth / to follow / to carry on / then / after that / subsequently / to proceed / to ensue / in turn / in one's turn

Today I encountered 继续 for the first time, and it has [this definition](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?wdqb=%E7%BB%A7%E7%BB%AD):

> to continue / to proceed with / to go on with

Are they mostly interchangeable? It looks like 接着 has a few more meanings, but are there any situations where 继续 is preferred? Are there any differences in tone or formality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of "接着" and "继续" can mean "to continue"(of course,either of them has other meanings), in this case, I would say "接着" must have an infinitive while "继续" may not have. Examples:

> 现在太晚了，明天再接着写吧。  **Right**  *It's too late now. [I suggest you]continue to write tomorrow.*
>   现在太晚了，明天再继续写吧。  **Right** *It's too late now. [I suggest you]continue to write tomorrow.*
>   现在太晚了，明天再继续吧。   **Right** *It's too late now. [I suggest you]continue tomorrow.*
>   现在太晚了，明天再接着吧。   **Wrong**

Answer (score 2):

接着 has the connotation of "picking up," after an interruption. Sometimes it could refer to "passing the baton" to another person.

继续 also means continue, but without the "picking up" connotation.

Answer (score 1):

except the meaning 'catch something', 接着 usually has a function as 'then' in English.
继续 means 'go on', 'continue'.